# Best way to convert multidimensional array to string

Tags: python, string, multidimensional-array

I have a Python multidimensional array:

```
list = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]
```

Is there any way to convert it to a string like this one?

```
# it must keep the brackets
string = "[[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]"
```

Of course, I could loop through the array and build my string, but I wanted to know if there's any other better option.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `result = "[" + ",".join([str(v) for v in list]) + "]"` - for 2d lists. Or just `str(list)`. It's that easy. You can .replace the spaces with ""

Comment: @LarrytheLlama Ok, this was my last option, but I was asking if is there any other option   :-)

Comment: I know it's your last option, but building it like this is how the computer does it. That is how it is supposed to work, not exceptions. Anyways, `str([[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]).replace(" ","")`

Comment: @LarrytheLlama  ok  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply you can use `str` method.

```
l = [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]
s = str(s)
print(s) # [[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]
print(type(s)) # <class 'str'>
print(s[0]) # [
```

Comment: I mistakenly believed this method could only be used to convert integers, decimals, etc. to string, not arrays

Comment: @LifeafterGuest Yes, Its a magical method :)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the string to JSON, to make output compact without spaces there is a [line in the docs with details](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump)

> To get the most compact JSON representation, you should specify (',', ':') to eliminate whitespace.

```
import json
json.dumps(list, separators=(',', ':'))  # '[[0,1,2],[3,4,5],[6,7,8]]'
```

Answer (score 1):

This keeps the brackets and converts it to a string.

```
string = str(list)
```